# ./Scripts/PodsLicenseCheck.sh: line 8: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ad_licenselint: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift

Application build successfully but if application run then this error

> produce ./Scripts/PodsLicenseCheck.sh: line 8:
> /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ad_licenselint: No such file or directory

I tried `pod reinstalled` , and apply these commands ,

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ruby,
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods,
```

But not resolved error

Comment: Try to delete derived data. There is an app for this in AppStore, and is super helpful, and easy to use.

Comment: i already deleted derived data but still not working and what app you are talking about

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.